# In Python, how will we convert this type of string into datetime format in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, format, logic

[image: This is the error, where the date format in string is shown, which I want to convert into datetime format how, we can do this?]

I have done:
1.

```
from datetime import datetime
date_string = df['Date']
format = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p'
for i in date_string:
    my_date = datetime.strptime(i, format)


print (my_date.strftime(format))
```

2. 

df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%m/%d/%Y, %I:%M %p')

Answer (score 0):

Use `%y` for years in format `YY`, `%Y` is for format `YYYY`:

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%m/%d/%y, %I:%M %p')
print (df)
                 Date
0 2018-02-26 12:31:00
```

Comment: Thank you! it was a pointless mistake, thanks